# Framerate capping in a fixed timestep game loop - Java

Tags: java, frame-rate, java-2d, game-loop

I am currently working on a Java 2D based game, and this is my current tutorial-based game loop:

```
public class FixedTSGameLoop implements Runnable
{
private MapPanel _gamePanel;

public FixedTSGameLoop(MapPanel panel) 
{
    this._gamePanel = panel;
}

@Override
public void run() 
{
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime(), now;
    double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int updates = 0;
    int frames = 0;
    while (this._gamePanel.isRunning())
    {
        now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        while (delta >= 1)
        {
            tick();
            updates++;
            delta--;
        }
        render();
        frames++;
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000)
        {
            timer += 1000;
            System.out.println("FPS: " + frames + " TICKS: " + updates);
            frames = 0;
            updates = 0;
        }
    }
}

private void tick()
{
    /**
     * Logic goes here:
     */
    this._gamePanel.setLogic();
}

private void render()
{
    /**
     * Rendering the map panel
     */
    this._gamePanel.repaint();
}
}
```

Now, I want to set a certain cap to the framerate. How do I do that in the most efficient way?
*Any other general tips concerning the game loop itself will be highly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Don't you already have a cap of 60fps?

Comment: The "ticking" is set to be called 60 times a second. The rate of rendering is not capped/set to a certain value currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I set up my game loop. You can change `frameCap` to any amount you would like.

```
    int frameCap = 120;
    int fps = 0;

    double delta = 0D;
    long last = System.nanoTime();
    long timer = 0L;

    while (true) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        long since = now - last;

        delta += since / (1000000000D / frameCap);
        timer += since;
        last = now;

        if (delta >= 1D) {
            tick();
            render();

            fps++;

            delta = 0D;
        }

        if (timer >= 1000000000L) {
            System.out.println("fps: " + fps);

            fps = 0;

            timer = 0L;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have to insert a "sleep" in your loop after render() in order to respect the 60fps limit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer camo5hark! BluEOS's comment was actually the tiny tip I needed to stop the rendering rate from going crazy high.